# Find the number of zeroes of $f(x)=\sin (8x)-x$ in the positive real axis.

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that the function
$$f(x)=\sin(8x)-x$$
has exactly three zeroes in the interval $(0,\infty)$.

How can I prove this? Grafically I see that there are two zeroes very near to $1$, and one in the interval $\left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]$. It seems unlikely that I can get a closed expression for all of them, and I don't even know how could I have discovered there are three zeroes without the help of graphics software (I'd like to do that, so if anyone has a way to find out there are three zeroes without relying on software, please tell me). At first sight I don't think I can use the Banach fixed point theorem freely in each interval.

Comment: Have you tried to locate the local maxima and minima? Also, it is enough to look for your zeroes in  $(0,1)$, because....

Comment: Oh. You just made me feel stupid (Don't worry about that).

Thanks. It goes that way.

Comment: No worries! Awesome nickname, btw :D

Comment: @Stefano ...because why ???

Comment: Because if $x >1$, then  $\sin(8x) - x$ is negative at a glance ($\sin$ of something is less or equal than $1$). Same for $x=1$. So since $\sin(8x)-x$ doesn't change sign in $[1,+\infty)$ its zeroes in $(0,+\infty)$ must be in $(0,1)$. @Rene Schipperus

Comment: @Stefano Thank-you.